# webpack resolve.alias with filename prefix

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

For this webpack alias `util`:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    util: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/util'),
  },
}
```

Each utility file is named like `util.name.js`. Is there a way to resolve the `util.` file prefix as part of the alias config?

For example, rather than importing like this:

```
import calc from 'util/util.calc';
```

Can I configure the webpack alias to handle this import syntax:

```
import calc from 'util/calc';
```

I'm using webpack 2.2.0-rc.3.

Comment: A bit late, but today you might use [`directory-named-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/shaketbaby/directory-named-webpack-plugin)